# SourceTree for Windows - how to show only my commits only in current feature (branch)

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

So I'm in my current branch in the Log/History window

- Combobox is select to "Current branch"
- Show Remote Branches is unchecked

and even when I go to search and filter by my author name, I see commits from my other features (because I merged).

I'm looking for source tree equivalent of this

```
git cherry -v develop
```

tl;dr I want to see only my commits and only my commits to the current feature (no other changes that got in during the merge)

Comment: run `git log <path/branch>` to view the log of your specific branch.

Comment: I was hoping for some native settings in SourceTree GUI. I find the git command line extremely confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SourceTree settings not contain all functions like the git commands have. And **there is no such setting in SourceTree** to show the log as `git cherry -v` does.

[image]

But you can view the log by inputting git commands on **SourceTree Terminal**. Any of below command can work:

```
git cherry -v
git log origin/branchname..branchname
```

Comment: Accepted the sad truth. I think Tortoise GIT has this functionality with some tinkering. It's just inconvenient to have two GIT programs.